# Odd behavior with UITabBarItem's text color in normal state

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Here is my code. If I put it into `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` of a subclass of `UITableViewController` it does not change the text color to white when the tab is selected. However, if i put it into `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` of a subclass navigationController, it behaviors correctly.

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"text" image:nil selectedImage:nil];
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor grayColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Can anyone tell me why?